# Как правильно записать свойства объекта в JS?

Tags: javascript

Задание:

> Свойством floors опишите количество этажей. Их обычно `4` или `5` — это максимальная высота дома, где по строительным нормам не нужен лифт. Отсутствие лифта в «хрущёвке» опишите свойством `hasElevator` со значением `false`. Хрущёвские дома бывают кирпичные и панельные. Для этого в объекте создадим свойство `type`, которое будет хранить соответствующую строку (`"кирпичный"` или `"панельный"`).

У меня получилось так:

```js
const building = {
  floors: '4 - 5',
  hasElevator: false,
  type: ["кирпичный", "панельный"],
};
```

- и это не правильно?
- как правильно записать?

Comment: Я думаю, что дом не может быть одновременно кирпичным и панельным, а также иметь количество этажей '4 - 5' :) Вероятно, вам нужно было дать пример с точными значениями, а не описать все возможные варианты

Comment: Ок) Но как правильно записать свойство type?
Что значит "или"? Правильно я что я создал массив?

Comment: Строкой - как по условию

Comment: Не понимаю как записать строкой что бы у ключа было два значения(

Comment: Это условие значит, что либо `type: "кирпичный"`, либо `type: "панельный"`, одновременно два значения быть не могут. Ну и с `floors` так же, они могут быть либо пять этажей, либо четыре, описывается одно из состояний: `floors: 4` или `floors: 5`. Выбирайте тот, который больше понравится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function Building(floors, hasElevator, type) {
  this.floors = floors;
  this.hasElevator = hasElevator;
  this.type = type;
}

var b1 = new Building(5, false, "панельный");
var b2 = new Building(4, false, "кирпичный");

console.log(b1);
console.log(b2);
```